# 'exifinterface' Dependency conflict when updating to targetSdkVersion 28

Tags: android, sdk, dependencies

Hello StackOverflow Community,

Everytime I update my projects to SdkVersion 28 and i haven't migrated to androidx library, i get a dependency conflict for my `com.android.support:xxx:28.0.0` libraries with the library `com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.0`.

Now I always import the library as `com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0` to fix that dependency conflict, but I'm not sure if this really is the right way, or if it's just the dirty and fast way.

Does anyone have the same problem and knows a better way to fix this bug without using exclude on each android dependency?